# k-grid-content not scrolling vertically if content overflows

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with the Kendo UI grid.

I increased the listings in the grid, but with initial load, the 'k-grid-content' does not show the scroll bar, and the content is more than what is currently displayed.

As can be seen below, the scrollable is set to true.

```
create: function (container) {
        this.container = container;
        $(container).kendoGrid({
            selectable: 'multiple',
            pageable: { refresh: true, buttonCount: 5, input: true },
            scrollable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            filterable: false,
            editable: true,
            resizable: true,
            columns: articleCategoryTab.grid.columns,
            dataBound: articleCategoryTab.events.onGridDataBound
        });
    },
```

I have tried to write some Javascript in the `dataBind` event, to give it a fixed height based on some calculation from the browser_height, but this did not work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, by placing the following in the `dataBind` event of the Kendo UI grid.

```
dataBind: function (ds) {
        this.get().setDataSource(ds);

        //make k-grid-content scrollable on initial load
        var BROWSER_HEIGHT = $(window).height();
        var diff = $('.container').height() +
        $('#articleManagementTabs').height() +
        $('#categoryArticleNavbar').height() +
        $('#categoryArticlePager').height() +
        $('#previewPaneWrapper').height();
        var difference = BROWSER_HEIGHT - diff - 10;

        var gridElement = $("#categoryArticleGrid");
        var dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content");
        dataArea.height(difference);
        dataArea.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you have provided an answer to your own question I thought I would provide a solution I came up with for **resizing** grids on the fly.

This is a function that I created which works for resizing grids and this can be applied to a number of different grids in one go and accounts for both locked and unlocked columns within grids

```
function initializeGrid(options)
{
    if(options === null || options === undefined)
    {
        options = {
            size: 0.55,
            gridContentCss: ".k-grid-content",
            gridLockedContentCss: ".k-grid-content-locked",
            gridsToResize:[]
        };
    }


    var windowHeight = $(window).height() * options.size;

    if(options.gridsToResize !== null && options.gridsToResize.length > 0 )
    {
        options.gridsToResize.forEach(function (item) {
            var gridContent = $('#' + item + ' > ' + options.gridContentCss);


            var lockedContent = $('#' + item + ' > ' + options.gridLockedContentCss);


          //  console.log(gridContent, lockedContent);

            gridContent.height(windowHeight);

            if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
                lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

            }
        }); 
    }
    else 
    {
        var gridContent = $(options.gridContentCss);
        var lockedContent = $(options.gridLockedContentCss);

        gridContent.height(windowHeight);

        if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
            lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

        }
    }



}
```

So this is called on the initial `document` ready event like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            initializeGrid(null); 
});
```

here is a demo of it in action: http://dojo.telerik.com/ALAnu

This simply uses a function called `initializeGrid` which accepts an options object that defines the **size**, **grid content css** indicators for both locked and unlocked portions of the grid and then an **array of grid ids** without the hash to resize. if no object is present then the function initialises its own version of this object and makes the assumption that there is only one grid on the screen at that moment in time to resize.

This works out the height based on a percentage of the overall window size and then adjusts the grid height based on that so by default the grid will occupy 55% of the available screen height. It is important not to provide an initial `height` value as this will override the height adjusting mechanics outlined above.

This obviously could be modified for your needs if you need it to take into account of other `elements` within the screen.

Comment: Thanks for you effort.